# Linux screen lock security

Tags: linux, security, cryptography

How secure is relying on the default screen lock in linux? What stops an attacker for just plugging a device that bruteforces the passord check? How secure should be my linux account password?

Comment: At least as secure as the password for your disk encryption, because someone who can plug in such a device can also possibly steal the computer (or just the disk). In fact you want the attacker to have steal the disk because this is something you'll easily notice.

Comment: What was the purpose of downvoting this question? Who here is hell bent on downvoting no matter what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physical access to a machine lets a malicious user bypass all sorts of things.

The screen lock, like a standard door lock, will prevent casual users from getting in and making changes.  You can add additional features such as lockouts for too many bad password attempts to prevent casual brute forcing methods.

A more determined user can boot into single-user mode if the boot loader is not protected, steal the whole computer if it is not securely attached to anything or remove the disk drive(s) if the case does not have a physical lock on it.  At that point it would not matter if you had a screen lock set, just like a door lock does not stop a determined burglar.

If that is a concern for you, you should have additional security measures in place for those situations.

Comment: This is probably one of the most important things to understand about information security, which _so_ may people never seem to get.  The moment you have physical access to a system and the ability to physically tamper with it, all software security measures are immediately irrelevant.