# How secure is it to suspend Linux (Fedora) while using whole disk encryption?

Tags: fedora, gnome, suspend, disk-encryption, screen-lock

I have a full disk encryption on my Fedora 33 workstation. The purpose of encryption was protection from stealing the laptop physically. But how much more unsafe to just suspend the OS, not fully poweroff? And what do you think about simple locking of the screen?

I've read related questions, such as [Linux screen lock security](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442572/linux-screen-lock-security) - but they discuss primarily the case without disk encryption.

Comment: When your return from suspend to RAM, do you have to enter the decrypt pass-phrase? Is anything kept in RAM that may be secret? Answering these questions will allow you to see the answer.

Comment: What would you do if your laptop was lost and then found? You can no longer trust it: if you enter your pass-phrase, then you may have given away all of your secrets.

Comment: Suspend-to-RAM is susceptible to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack.  Not sure about suspend-to-disk.  I use suspend-to-RAM myself, except when I'm traveling.  Which, thanks to Covid, is kinda moot now :)